# Ruby on Rails Devise Weird Double Login Required Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am encountering an issue that has left me quite stumped, mainly:

1. I have a Ruby on Rails app running on a server
2. For some users, login fails the first time (though the login details are correct), and succeeds the second time

Since this issue is dependent on what I am using, these are the main details:

1. rails (4.2.5.1)
2. devise (3.4.1)
3. ruby (2.3.0)
4. server - Ubuntu 14.04

extracted lines from the log:

```
*** POST is done to sign in the user ***
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for <ip-1> at 2016-06-13 15:23:25 +0800
Redirected to https://app.blimp.sg/users/
Completed 302 Found in 116ms (ActiveRecord: 7.9ms)

*** Some data needs to be cached on the client-side's localStorage ***
*** So the user is redirected to "/users/after_login" on successful sign in ***
Started GET "/users/after_login?after_initialization_url=" for <ip-1> at 2016-06-13 15:23:29 +0800
Chrome 51.0.2704.84 (Windows, Windows 7)

*** The UsersController#after_login redirects to the sign in page ***
*** if the user is not logged in ***
*** !! The main issue is here, it should not redirect to the sign in page !! ***
Processing by UsersController#after_login as HTML
Redirected to http://app.blimp.sg/users/sign_in
Completed 302 Found in 46ms (ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)

*** The user lands on the sign in page again ***
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for <ip-1> at 2016-06-13 15:23:31 +0800
Processing by Users::SessionsController#new as HTML

*** The user tries to sign in again *** 
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for <ip-1> at 2016-06-13 15:24:03 +0800
Redirected to https://app.blimp.sg/users/after_login?after_initialization_url=
Completed 302 Found in 143ms (ActiveRecord: 7.6ms)    

*** The user is redirected to the "users/after_login" page again ***
Started GET "/users/after_login?after_initialization_url="

*** This time the action completes with a 200 OK response ***
*** Instead of the user being redirected ***
Processing by UsersController#after_login as HTML
Completed 200 OK in 602ms (Views: 543.5ms | ActiveRecord: 6.2ms)
```

I've omitted some lines, but the client is recorded as "Chrome 51.0.2704.84 (Windows, Windows 7)" for all requests

For the UsersController#after_login action, there is only one redirect line in the entire action, the code is:

```
if !app_user.is_signed_in?
  redirect_to new_user_session_path
end
```

Things I have tried to debug this:

1. I thought it might be an expired CSRF token for the login page, so in my Users::SessionsController, I have added:

   skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:create]

But this did not resolve the issue.

Other than that, I have inspected the logs but not much luck on it.
It seems to happen for different users, but I have not been able to reproduce the issue on my side.

Would appreciate any help or information on what might be causing this issue, or advice on how to go about finding out what is the issue.

## Update 1

Requested Sessions Controller code:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  skip_after_action :verify_authorized
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:create]
  # before_filter :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  def new
    response.headers.delete "X-Frame-Options"
    super
  end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  # def create
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  def destroy
    signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out :    sign_out(resource_name))
    render json: {message: "signed out"}
  end

  # protected

  # You can put the params you want to permit in the empty array.
  # def configure_sign_in_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) << :attribute
  # end
end
```

## Update 2

I decided to add more logging output to help understand what is going on.
In Users::SessionsController, added:

```
def new
  response.headers.delete "X-Frame-Options"
  super
  logger.info "SessionsController#new:: app_user.is_signed_in?=#{app_user.is_signed_in?}"
  logger.info "SessionsController#new: session['warden.user.user.key']=#{session['warden.user.user.key']}"
end

def create
  super
  logger.info "SessionsController#create:: app_user.is_signed_in?=#{app_user.is_signed_in?}"
  logger.info "SessionsController#create: session['warden.user.user.key']=#{session['warden.user.user.key']}"
end
```

and in UsersController added:

```
def after_login
  skip_authorization

  logger.info "UsersController#after_login:: app_user.is_signed_in?=#{app_user.is_signed_in?}"
  logger.info "UsersController#after_login: session['warden.user.user.key']=#{session['warden.user.user.key']}"
  ... 

  if !app_user.is_signed_in?
    logger.info "Redirecting to new_user_session_path because app_user.is_signed_in?=#{app_user.is_signed_in?}"
    redirect_to new_user_session_path
  end
```

Will post another update when the issue occurs and I get the additional output from the above logs.

## Update 3

Have managed to get the additional output of the above from the logs

```
*** POST to sign in ***
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for <ip-1> at 2016-06-15 09:57:46 +0800

*** Sign in completes successfully ***
*** User is redirected to "users/after_login" page ***
*** session['warden.user.user.key'] has a set value ***
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as HTML
Redirected to https://app.blimp.sg/users/after_login?after_initialization_url=
SessionsController#create:: app_user.is_signed_in?=true
SessionsController#create: session['warden.user.user.key']=[[<id-1>], "<session-key-1>"]
Completed 302 Found in 104ms (ActiveRecord: 4.1ms)

Started GET "/users/after_login?after_initialization_url=" for <ip-1> at 2016-06-15 09:57:47 +0800

*** session['warden.user.user.key'] has been lost and is now empty ***
Processing by UsersController#after_login as HTML
UsersController#after_login:: app_user.is_signed_in?=false
UsersController#after_login: session['warden.user.user.key']=
Redirecting to new_user_session_path because app_user.is_signed_in?=false
Redirected to http://app.blimp.sg/users/sign_in
Completed 302 Found in 45ms (ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)

*** Redirected to sign in page again ***
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for <ip-1> at 2016-06-15 09:57:47 +0800
Processing by Users::SessionsController#new as HTML
SessionsController#new:: app_user.is_signed_in?=false
SessionsController#new: session['warden.user.user.key']=

*** Second login attempt ***
*** session['warden.user.user.key'] is again set with the same value ***
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for <ip-1> at 2016-06-15 09:57:59 +0800
Redirected to https://app.blimp.sg/users/after_login?after_initialization_url=
SessionsController#create:: app_user.is_signed_in?=true
SessionsController#create: session['warden.user.user.key']=[[<id-1>], "<session-key-1>"]

*** This time the session['warden.user.user.key'] is not lost ***
Started GET "/users/after_login?after_initialization_url=" for <ip-1> at 2016-06-15 09:57:59 +0800
Processing by UsersController#after_login as HTML
UsersController#after_login:: app_user.is_signed_in?=true
UsersController#after_login: session['warden.user.user.key']=[[<id-1>], "<session-key-1>"]

Completed 200 OK in 335ms (Views: 311.1ms | ActiveRecord: 4.4ms)
```

It seems the session is indeed successfully created the first time, but seems to become lost somehow, any ideas on what might cause this?

## Update 4

Thinking more about the issue, I realized a possibility is that these users were accessing the site from the old subdomain, the site has two domains: beta.domain.com and app.domain.com

Unfortunately, my server logs do not have the full URL so I am unable to verify this at the moment, but I will update the site to automatically redirect any user from beta.domain.com to app.domain.com and monitor if the issue persists.

Comment: can you show us your sessions controller

Comment: @ChiragArya sure, have added the code under **Update 1**

Comment: why have you got your create action commented [:devise sessions controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb) have a look at this you can modify and handle login's as per you want with just little modifications

Comment: @John Are you sure the `is_signed_in?` method is correct? I don't think it's a Devise method.

Comment: Are you positive that the first sign in isn't creating a session?  What happens if you navigate to an authenticated page after the initial sign in?

Comment: @ChiragArya the actions are commented out by default, I followed the steps in *Configuring controllers* from https://github.com/plataformatec/devise, for my case I just wanted to customize the "new" and "destroy" actions, so the other actions are not overwritten and left as commented out

Comment: @PoloniculMov this is a custom function I added, due to the app requirements, it is defined as 
`def is_signed_in?
    id.present? && approved?
end`

Comment: @tagCincy I am not positive that the first sign in doesn't create a session, I'm wondering if it is possible that the session is created but somehow lost, I do not have access to test what happens if navigation is made to an authenticated page.

What I am sure of is that the UsersController#after_login action is called and results in a redirect, I am also certain that there is only one reason why a redirect happens in this action and that is at 
`if !app_user.is_signed_in?
          redirect_to new_user_session_path
        end`

Comment: The difficulty I face in solving this is that I am unable to reproduce the error, and I have not encountered the issue first hand, though I get reports from users that they encounter this issue, but it does not happen consistently even for these users

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, I've decided to add more logging to help understand the issue (posted under **Update 2**), let me know if you think there are any additional logs I should add to help solve the issue

Comment: managed to get the additional output from the logs, have posted this under **Update 3**