# Devise sign_in endpoint returns malformed session cookie on first call, but works OK on two successive sign_in calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, warden

OK
We have an application which has been working great. A few weeks ago a (now ex) employee made, quite a massive change which seemed to have caused a rather peculiar bug and I'm trying to figure out what the actual problem is and of course solve it.

In short, here is a scenario which fails:

### POST Sign In & GET user info

In the application we use devise(4.6.2 I believe) for authenticating users and CanCanCan for authorization of resources and Ahoy for tracking certain types of users (admins in this case).

We have two relevant routes for the failure we're experiencing:

1. `/users/sign_in` <- This is a devise route
2. `GET /user` <- This is a route which returns some relevant information regarding the current user including the user role and a **JWT token** which they can use to perform API calls

The `GET /user` endpoint is defined inside a controller: `UsersController < V2::ApplicationController`, the Application controller has a few hooks in it, the relevant one is: `before_action :authenticate_user!, :update_current_session`, where `update_current_session` looks like this:

```
def current_session
    return unless current_user
    @current_session ||= current_user.sessions.find_by_session_id(cookies.signed[:_session_id])
end

def update_current_session
    return unless current_session
    current_session.accessed!(request)
end
```

So from what I understand, `authenticate_user!` uses devise and then calls the update_current_session function.

### Happy Flow - How things worked before:

We have a few internal tests/scripts that need the token that `/user` returns because they perform API calls to our application. Thus they did the following:

1. Perform a POST call to `/users/sign_in` with a body that looks like

```
{
    "user": {
            "email": "email@email.com",
            "password": "whatever"
    }
}
```

2. Get a 200 OK response with body `success: "true"`.
3. This sets some cookies (the response has a few `Set-Cookie` headers:

```
Set-Cookie: ahoy_visit=[REDACTED]; path=/; expires=Mon, 20 Apr 2020 13:34:21 GMT; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: _session_id=[REDACTED]; path=/; expires=Mon, 20 Apr 2020 10:34:21 GMT; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: st_session=[REDACTED]; path=/; expires=Wed, 20 May 2020 09:34:21 GMT; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: _safe_cookies__known_cookies=ahoy_visitor%7Cahoy_visit%7C_session_id%7Cst_session; path=/; expires=Thu, 18 Apr 2030 09:34:21 GMT; HttpOnly
```

4. Call GET `/user` with the header `Cookie` which is just all those Set-Cookie params together (or just multiple `Cookie` headers, both work
5. Receive a 200 OK response with the relevant body.

In conclusion:

1. POST sign_in - receive a set of cookies
2. Call GET /user with cookies
3. Success

### Failures since change

Ever since that ex-employees change the relevant flow described above fails. The current situation is this:

1. POST sign_in - receive a set of cookies
2. Call GET /user with cookies
3. **Receive 401 Unauthorized**

After trying to figure out whats wrong (mainly through Postman and some scripts), I noticed something quite odd:

On the first call of POST `/users/sign_in`, the **st_session** cookie seems to be **shorter** than it was before.
If we call POST `/users/sign_in` twice in succession then the flow works:

1. POST sign_in - receive a set of cookies (st_session seems to be malformed or missing something)
2. POST sign_in again - receive a set of cookies (now st_session looks OK)
3. Call GET /user with cookies
4. Works - receives proper response from server

The `st_session` seems to be due to the configuration inside `session_store.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: 'st_session', expire_after: (Rails.env.production? ? 1.hour : 1.month), secure: Rails.env.production?
```

### Summary

Before the change, the following flow worked OK:

1. POST sign_in - receive a set of cookies
2. Call GET /user with cookies
3. Success

After the change, the flow fails with 401:

1. POST sign_in - receive a set of cookies
2. Call GET /user with cookies
3. **Receive 401 Unauthorized**

Calling sign_in twice in succession works:

1. POST sign_in
2. POST sign_in again
3. Call GET /user with cookies
4. Works - receives proper response from server

## Debugging/Figuring out what's wrong

I've looked at `devise.rb` and our `sessions_controller` but it seems that the 401 failure is happening outside of these places.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this issue? I've trying to debug and find where the problem lies but I can't seem to make relevant progress. It seems to be something related to Devise/Warden but I'm not too familiar with what's going on there.

I would preferably like to know who stores the `st_session` cookie and **what** is stored in it, because it seems like the first time it's missing something (because the st_session) is shorter, and it looks like devise can't correctly authenticate the user based on that value.

Any help is appreciated, even direct me to relevant places in the code I could look for answers/help debugging

Thank you.

Comment: Just out of the curiosity - Have you actually taken a look into the commit of what changes your ex-employee did?  That might give you some insight to what he/she/they changed and where to look. For me, this looks like it has either changed the devise controller or something similar. And it looks very similar to this question though -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37811444/ruby-on-rails-devise-weird-double-login-required-issue

Comment: yes of course @mutantkeyboard first thing we did :) Problem is it was a rails upgrade pull request which includes 140 file changes and several gem updates
I'm thinking it's related to some gem update rather than a code since the first commit which updates several gems (rails to v5 being one of them) already fails the test above

Comment: One the things here which is highly atypical and likely the root of your problems is that this is using multiple sessions instead of just a single session and that its doing this on the controller layer instead of with Warden on the rack layer. This is not how to handle authentication with Devise.

Comment: @max how did you realize this?, I'm genuinely asking since I'm not that knowledgeable regarding user/server sessions and in rails especially

Comment: `current_user.sessions.find_by_session_id` is kind of a dead giveaway that whoever wrote this is storing something in a sessions table or its some kind of legacy holdover from when Rails used a database session storage. This is not something you want to do. With the cookie store you always treat the session as singular. The client has one session store cookie wand when you invalidate its identifier its null and void.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue, and it was caused by Devise's `:timeoutable`

If there are any `current_user` calls in your `ApplicationController`, they will trigger the authentication process.

Because the session timed out, it will trigger a 401 error before it will reach the sign in code in the sessions controller.

The solution for me was to add to the sessions controller the following line:

`prepend_before_action :reset_session, only: [:create]`